# How to add a class to html element dynamically using razor syntax?

Tags: razor

I want to add class to a `<tr>` element depending on model's attribute:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
     if (item.Level == 1)
     {
       <tr class="classA">
     }
     else if (item.Level == 2)
     {
       <tr class="classB">
     }
     else
     {
       <tr>
     }

     <td>...</td>
     <td>...</td>         

     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

My IDE tells me my `<tr>` element is not closed. How can I dynamically add the class value using razor?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I would use the ternary operator ? and write something like that.

```
<tr class="@(item.Level==1?"classA":item.Level == 2?"classB":"")">
```

It isn't very readable, and won't work with complex comparaisons. In these cases, I would suggest you to declare a method in the razor view

```
@functions{ 
  public string GetClassFromLevel(int level) 
    {
        return level == 1 ? "classA" : level == 2 ? "classB" : "";
  }
}

<tr class"@GetClassFromLevel(item.Level)">
```

Comment: Don't forget to set the question as answered ;)