# How can I change the style to an HTML element that doesn't have ID using javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css, razor-pages

I know what I want but forgive me because I can barely figure out how to ask it in a concise way. I have done quite a bit of searching for an answer. None of the suggested "duplicates" apply as far as I can see.

Goal:
To change background-color of div based on the dance's style using javascript function. Page loads, any dance style's background-color is set based on style.

My Razor Page loops thru and lists dance events. (other columns have been removed to allow focus on the problem.)

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Dances)
{  
<tr>
    <td>
        <div> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DanceStyle) </div>
    </td> 
</tr>
}
```

Because there are many dynamic rows, the div element does not contain an ID. Hence, I cannot call a javascript function sending the Dance's style and use GetElementByID to set the back color of the DIV.

Below is just a rough attempt for what I thought might work.

```
<div onload="fColorDIV(this.value)"> DanceStyle </div>

function fColorDIV(this)
{
        switch(this)
        {
            case "Waltz":
                dancestyleBGcolor = "PapayaWhip"
                break;
            case "WCS":
                dancestyleBGcolor = "LightSalmon"
                break;
            case "Zydeco/Cajun":
                dancestyleBGcolor = "Yellow"
                break;

            default:
                dancestyleBGcolor = "LightGray"
         } 
    return dancestyleBGcolor;

}
```

I doubt onload even works when DIV is being written to page. Adding an ID would not work because all rows would have the same ID in their DIV.

Comment: When exactly do you want to change the bg-color?

Comment: Well, the plan was anytime before the page is viewed, hence client side javascript. I can't envision doing it on the C# code behind OnGet. But. . . . I am all ears

Comment: Why not add a class according to the content to the divs when creating them at back-end?

Comment: class means class attribute to the div. Why do you think it will overkill. It is just to differentiate what div is what.

Comment: If I've understood your code correctly, you could use `item.DanceStyle` as a classname. Only that there seems to be some nasty characters, modify the name so that it contains only four - five first characters to avoid escaping ..?

Comment: @JustJohn This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123067/how-to-add-a-class-to-html-element-dynamically-using-razor-syntax The example uses tr element, you have div

Comment: Hi CodeThing,
I think your example that uses the tr element and the ternary operator might work. There are tons of styles/colors, but I think the missing link was how to reference the class function using the ternary operator. @Teemu, I think I understand what you are saying.  I will try this and get back to you guys.

Comment: I guess I will add my own answer if no one complains. I'm not sure how to give you guys credit.

Answer (score 0):

@CodeThing helped me by pointing me to
[How to add a class to html element dynamically using razor syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123067/how-to-add-a-class-to-html-element-dynamically-using-razor-syntax)

I made the assumption from the example using class attribute that it would work for style and/or any HTML attribute was correct.

I currently got it working on style attribute by calling function in class (thank you @Temu) and setting style attribute for DIV plus a couple other things like border radius and text-align.

```
 <div style="background-color:@DaBamba.Helpers.NextEvent.AddStyleColor(item.DanceStyle);border-radius:10px;text-align:center;"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DanceStyle)</div>
```

And here is the function I call in a class I have:

```
 public static string AddStyleColor(string thisStyle)
        {
            string dancestyleBGcolor = "";
            switch (thisStyle)
            {
                case "All Styles":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "White";
                    break;
                case "Balkan":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "Bisque";
                    break;
                case "Ballroom":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "#6699FF";
                    break;
                case "Bhangra":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "#9900CC";
                    break;
                case "Blues":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "AliceBlue";
                    break;
                case "Contra":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "Wheat";
                    break;
                case "Country":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "BurlyWood";
                    break;
                case "English Country":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "GreenYellow";
                    break;
                case "Ecstatic":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "Lime";
                    break;
                case "Folk Also":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "Black";
                    break;
                case "Irish":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "SpringGreen";
                    break;
                case "Israeli":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "LightCoral";
                    break;
                case "Misc/Variety":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "Honeydew";
                    break;
                case "Polka":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "PeachPuff";
                    break;
                case "Salsa":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "PowderBlue";
                    break;
                case "Scottish":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "MistyRose";
                    break;
                case "Scandinavian":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "White";
                    break;
                case "Square":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "#993333";
                    break;
                case "Square(neo)":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "Aquamarine";
                    break;
                case "Swing/Lindy":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "LightSkyBlue";
                    break;
                case "Tango":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "Thistle";
                    break;
                case "Waltz":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "PapayaWhip";
                    break;
                case "WCS":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "LightSalmon";
                    break;
                case "Zydeco/Cajun":
                    dancestyleBGcolor = "Yellow";
                    break;

                default:

                    dancestyleBGcolor = "LightGray";
                    break;

          }


            return dancestyleBGcolor;
        }
```